# wsimport multiple generated wsdl's

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jbossws

I am using jbossws (with jax-ws) to serve 3 webservices generated from annotated POJOs.
These 3 webservices share a few data classes and also have a common method (`ping`).
They all reside in the same java package (`namespace`)

The 3 WSDL files are generated automatically by `jbossws` at deploy time.

Now I want to generate client code using wsimport.

When I import the WSDL files one by one, this somehow works allthough there are some quirks (`ObjectFactory.java` overwritten, `@XmlSeeAlso` not listing all subclasses)

When I import the 3 WSDL files in one go, the tool starts complaining about duplicate definitions (e.g. `[ERROR] 'ping' is already defined`) and does not generate anything.

I have tried changing namespaces, but that would lead to several packages and perhaps duplication of some classes on the client side.

How do I generate code for the 3 WSDL files, that results in no duplicate code, correct `@XmlSeeAlso` annotations, and preferably a correct `ObjectFactory`?

Comment: I've given up on this. I am now using Maven wsimport mojo, and that doesn't allow me to run a single wsimport with multiple WSDLs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by using the -extension flag to see if it just "works". The extensions sometimes help, particularly with duplicate property names.

If the problem is a method/property name collision, you'll probably have to customize it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I've given up on this.
I am now using Maven wsimport mojo, and that doesn't even run a single wsimport with multiple WSDLs.